# What is the difference between quarterly GDP and annual GDP?

Tags: macroeconomics

I didn't understand how quarterly GDP is calculated. If GDP means Gross Domestic Product in a year, then what does quarterly GDP mean Gross Domestic Product in a quarter? OR it is multiplied by $4$ to estimate for a annual number? I appreciate the help. I tried google but cannot seem to find a page that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

You might not find a page explaining (in an easy manner) how quarterly GDP is calculated because it is done by several different means in different countries and the calculation/estimation methods can get confusing. If you want to know how a certain country generates a quarterly GDP figure, you should check the country's official economic statistics page - the descriptions of the statistic usually list at least something about the collection process.

Usually quarterly GDP is done with a smaller sample and has some estimations done (often based on last year's data). Annual GDP is usually the more accurate measure with a larger sample and more revision time between collection of data and publishing it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stats.OECD](http://stats.oecd.org/) web site answers all your questions and offers useful data!

Here is an [OECD document](http://www.oecd.org/std/na/1909562.pdf) explaining the sources and methods used by OECD member countries to compute ***quarterly*** national accounts. As explained in the document, most of the OECD countries use 3 types of approach to construct GDP figures: the production approach, the expenditure approach, and the income approach. Among others, those approaches rely on surveys of households and firms.

For the ***annual*** figures, the OECD maintains a useful [FAQs page](http://www.oecd.org/std/na/annualnationalaccountsfaqs.htm), with answers on What is a GDP? How is it calculated? When are the annual national accounts revised? Etc... The source and methods web page is [here](http://www.oecd.org/eco/outlook/sources-and-methods.htm)

Quarterly or annual data for OECD countries can be found [here](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=qna)